# Can the double downloads in pages with <link rel="subresource" ...> tags be avoided for user refresh requests?

Tags: optimization, google-chrome

When a user refreshes/reloads a web page, this results in HTTP requests with `max-age=0`. Pages utilizing the `prefetch` or `subresource` feature (e.g. tags like `<link rel="subresource" href="/code.js">` in the `head`) will then see two such fetches, at least from Chrome. Unlike regular page requests, Chrome does not appear to cache and indeed downloads the resource twice.

Is there a way to prevent this waste of resources? Can I hint to browsers that the `prefetch` and `subresource` features are only meant for regular page loads, or that even on a user-initiated page refresh they should cache it for at least one second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `rel=subresource` has yet to be implemented in any browser unlike `rel=prefetch` which has been. As for Chrome development there is this issue ticket you can follow: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=312327

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000590/link-rel-subresource-href-file-doesnt-cache-despite-having-correct-cache-h

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is going to remove support for `<link rel=subresource>` as it's not useful, proprietary, and buggy: https://crbug.com/581840

Use `<link rel=preload>` instead.